# Table Anchor Click Get Parent Class Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html code:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="user_id" value="18">
    <a class="contactnow" href="#" onclick="contactnow();">Contact Now</a>
</td>
```

my javascript function is as follow's:

```
function contactnow()
{
    var id=$(this).parent('.user_id').val();
    alert(id);
}
```

I need to get the value of hidden field on click on this anchor, these anchor's are multiple on same page as looping data from database.

Comment: `$(this)` isn't going to refer to what you think it will, and how is the input a parent of the link?

Comment: It refers to `undefined` I think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass reference in onclick attribute.

```
<a class="contactnow" href="#" onclick="contactnow(this);">Contact Now</a>
```

use this

```
function contactnow(e)
{
   var id=$(e).parent().find('.user_id').val();
   //or
   var id=$(e).siblings('.user_id').val();
   alert(id);
}
```

However instead of using javascript in html attributes you can separate your javascript entirely which is lot more cleaner and you don't have to repeat `onclick` everytime for it to work in multiple elements. Remove onclick attribute

Html

```
<a class="contactnow" href="#">Contact Now</a>
```

JS

```
$('.contactnow').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).parent().find('.user_id').val();
    //or
    var id=$(this).siblings('.user_id').val();
    alert(id);
});

// if you are using dynamically added element use

 $(document).on('click','.contactnow', function(){
    var id=$(this).parent().find('.user_id').val();
    //or
    var id=$(this).siblings('.user_id').val();
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the inline event handler and use:

```
$('a.contactnow').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).prev('input').val())
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8bz1trod/)**

As I commented above, `$(this)` isn't what you think it is since you pass nothing to your function. The you need the `.prev()` element, not the `.parent()`.

Comment: OP can remove `onclick="contactnow();"` from his HTML ;)

Comment: The issue is when i fetch data from ajax the whole div's this function not works

Comment: When did AJAX become part of your question? There's nothing in your question about it. Use the event delegation syntax of `.on()` if you're dynamically adding elements. Ex `$(document).on('click','a.contactnow', function()...)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to use the inline event handler you need to pass the this keyword.

Change:

```
onclick="contactnow();"
```

to:

```
onclick="contactnow(this, event);"
```

```js
function contactnow(ele, e)
{
  var id=$(ele).siblings('.user_id').val();
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="user_id" value="18">
            <a class="contactnow" href="#" onclick="contactnow(this, event);">Contact Now</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tag jquery, here is an simple example of it.

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var answer = $(this).prev().val();
    alert(answer) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="4">
<button>click me</button>
```